# How do I compare a CSS variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I want to check if a CSS variable is 0px, and then to `console.log` a message saying "Make Big". This is the if statement I have tried using:

```
const root = document.documentElement
const toggleNavButton = document.querySelector('.nav-dropdown');

toggleNavButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue('--mobile-navbar-height'))
    if (getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue('--mobile-navbar-height') === '0px') {
        console.log('Make big');
    }
});
```

And this is the CSS variable:

```
:root {
    --mobile-navbar-height: 0px;
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Frontend - Sign Up</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/styles.css">
        <script defer src="../scripts/UI_Manager.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="top-nav">
                <ul class="nav-link-container">
                    <li class="nav-item nav-all">TITLE</li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-full">ITEM 1</li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-full">ITEM 2</li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-full">ITEM 3</li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
                        <span></span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the ouput in the console:

https://prnt.sc/x45osr

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What does `getComputedStyle(root)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is returning  `0px` (There is a space before the 0)

Example comparing with a space:

```js
const root = document.documentElement
const toggleNavButton = document.querySelector('.nav-dropdown');

toggleNavButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var style = getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue('--mobile-navbar-height')
  console.log(style)
  if (style === ' 0px') {
    console.log('Make big');
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  --mobile-navbar-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button type='button' class='nav-dropdown'>Dropdown example</button>
```

You can either expect that in the comparison, or `.trim()` the string to remove extra space at the start/end before doing the comparison (Trimming is likely more reliable)

Trimming example:

```js
const root = document.documentElement
const toggleNavButton = document.querySelector('.nav-dropdown');

toggleNavButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var style = getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue('--mobile-navbar-height').trim()
  console.log(style)
  if (style === '0px') {
    console.log('Make big');
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  --mobile-navbar-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button type='button' class='nav-dropdown'>Dropdown example</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim the value you are getting extra space

change line

```
getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue('--mobile-navbar-height') === '0px'
```

to

```
getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue('--mobile-navbar-height').trim() === '0px'
```